# Returning Data From Server To Page Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I wanted to know if I can pass back individual parameters from a php script to be stored in dfferent JS variables on the page I'm working on, while also returning generated html code from the php script along with those parameters.

Basically I would like to return some data like this from php using ajax:

```
$valid = "true";
$access = "false";
$htmlcontent="lorem ipsum<br/>some more text<b>bold</b>";
```

And all of this should go into equivalent javascript variables on my page, using ajax, so that I can contruct my response on the page using this data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the data to an array and `json_encode` then:

```
$ret = array();
$ret["valid"] = "true";
$ret["access"] = "false";
$ret["htmlcontent"] ="lorem ipsum<br/>some more text<b>bold</b>";
echo json_encode($ret);
```

And in your client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"your_script.php",
    success:function(resp) {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(resp)
        alert(json.valid)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let PHP print them directly as JS variables. It also saves your client one HTTP request.

```
<script>
    var valid = <?= $valid ?>;
    var access = <?= $access ?>;
    var htmlcontent = <?= json_encode($htmlcontent) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: firs carefull with php short tags , and second what if he needs to build the variables depending on the users actions tracked with js ? he would need ajax instead of reloading the page .